# FusionDirectory: OpenLDAP with SSL or TLS

Tags: linux, security, ssl, tls, openldap

I have looked around and found a lot online about how to set up TLS for OpenLDAP. The basic idea is adding the olcTLS items to include cert, key, cacert in `cn=config`.

However, with [FusionDirectory](https://www.fusiondirectory.org), trying to use `ldapmodify` tells me that `cn=config` does not exist, and when I try to create `cn=config`, it tells me (logged in as the LDAP admin) that I don't have the rights to create it. I was following [these](https://www.theo-andreou.org/?p=1539) instructions.

So I resorted to editing the file `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif` to add the following items:

```
olcTLSCACertificate: /etc/ssl/certs/ca.cert
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/fd.cert
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/fd.key
olcTLSCipherSuite: SECURE256
olcTLSVerifyClient: try
```

I also edited `/etc/default/slapd` to include `SLAPD_SERVICES="ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldaps:///"`

- I added the openldap user to the ssl-cert group.
- I restarted slapd.
- Using ldapvi, `cn=config` can't be found.
- But `slapcat -n0 | grep -i tls` shows the olcTLS* entries I forcibly added to the file.
- Using Wireshark, I can see that when the client requests START_TLS, the server says okay, and shows supported ciphers. The client begins an SSL Hello, and the server responds with TCP FIN.
- `nmap` shows that ports 389 & 636 are open, and also shows the certificate information (Issuer: commonName=MyServer/organizationName=Testing), public key type: rsa, public key bits: 4096, and the MD5 and SHA1 hashes of the cert. So it's able to read the cert & key, permissions are fine.

However, SSL (636) and TLS(389) connections fail. Unencrypted 389 connections work just fine, except that in Wireshark I see wayy too much information and it makes me uncomfortable.

So whats the deal here?

- OS is Debian Jessie 8.7
- FusionDirectory 1.0.20
- OpenLDAP 2.4.40
- Certs created with [gnomint](http://gnomint.sourceforge.net/) with TLS extensions.

**Edit 15 May 2017:**

I ran `openssl s_client -connect host.local -showcerts` and it showed the certificate, negotiated ciphers, etc.

```
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: 
RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: 
RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-521, 521 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4512 bytes and written 511 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 5120 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 37EAADA00459F296BE972FB57B4A5....
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 0F865CBEDA755F84E783.....
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1494883911
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
```

However, `ldapsearch` doesn't work:

```
# ldapsearch -H ldaps://host.local:636 -xLL -v
ldap_initialize( ldaps://host.local:636/??base )
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

So the SSL part works, but not the rest of it.